# SnapKit - UITableView height is not change with dynamical content of cell

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview, snapkit

I'm a beginner in SnapKit, I want to implement a UITableViewController with SnapKit, each row have two UILabel, one of them is Title and another one is Value.
My issue is the height of the row in UITableView not changed according to the content of each row.
here is my code: 
class ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

// MARK: Property List
var list: NSMutableArray?
let myTableView: UITableView = {
   let table = UITableView()
    return table
}()

//MARK: Life Cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.myTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    self.myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    title = "TableView Page"
    setup()
    setupViews()

}

// MAKR: Setup View
func setup() {
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}

func setupViews () {
    self.view.addSubview(myTableView)
    myTableView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
        make.top.left.bottom.right.equalTo(10)
    }
    myTableView.register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CustomCell.customCell)
    myTableView.delegate = self
    myTableView.dataSource = self
}

// MARK: TableView DataSource
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCell.customCell, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.title.text = "title is lognest??"
    cell.value.text = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) ?
     "longest value longest value longest value longest value longest value longest value longest value for text"
        : "short value"
    cell.title.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(cell.value.snp.top)
        make.left.equalTo(20)
        make.trailing.equalTo(cell.value.snp.leading)
    }
    cell.value.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.right.equalTo(-20)
        make.top.equalTo(cell.title.snp.top)
        make.bottom.equalTo(-10)
    }

    NSLog("value height is: \(cell.value.frame.height)")
    NSLog("cell height is: \(cell.frame.height)")
        return cell;
    }    
}
```

class CustomCell:

```
// MARK: custom cell
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

// MARK: Property
static var customCell = "cell"
public var title:UILabel = {
    let tit = UILabel()
    tit.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    tit.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    tit.textColor = .black
    tit.alpha = 0.6
    return tit
}()
public var value:UILabel = {
    let val = UILabel()
    val.textColor = .black
    val.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    val.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    val.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    val.numberOfLines = 0
    val.alpha = 0.75
    return val
}()

// MARK: initializer
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.addSubview(title)
        self.addSubview(value)
}

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)")
    }
}
```

And this is console logs:

> snapkitTest[26345:1387159] cell height is: 44.0 
>   snapkitTest[26345:1387159] value height is: 0.0

[image: Screen Shot of TableView on iPhone XR]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1- You have to add the label to

```
self.contentView.addSubview(title)
```

2- You need to set bottom constraint to contentView

```
title.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.trailing.equalTo(value.snp.leading)
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.top).inset(10)
        make.left.equalTo(20)
    }
value.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.right.equalTo(-40)
        make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.snp.top).inset(10)
        make.bottom.equalTo(-10)
    }
```

Also transfer this constraints to init of cell custom class , as not to re-add constraints every scroll of tableView